# clipsToBounds / masksToBounds not working for image view in table view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I had done it several times, it worked fine, but i don't know what am I missing this time. The Problem is that image inside image view is not being clipped to bounds.

In simulator it is shown like this:

[image]

Inside the table view cell class, in my `awakeFromNib()` method i have following code:

```
override func awakeFromNib()
{
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.size.width / 2
        
        profileImageView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        profileImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
}
```

but still as you see in the image, the image inside image view is coming out of the bounds, whereas circular border is correctly applied.

I have tried to put this code inside `layoutSubviews()` method in tableViewCell class, as well as i have also tried to apply this cornerRadius inside `cellForRowAt` method of table view.
Moreover, i have also tried changing the properties of image view to Aspect Fit and Scale To Fit from storyboard.

Nothing is working, The image is still shown outside the circular bounds! why ?

**EDIT:** Screenshot of my storyboard, where i had a prototype cell, with image view in it

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the `.image` property of `profileImageView`? From your screen-shot it *looks* like you have two image views. Is this from a Storyboard Cell Prototype? Or are you configuring the cell (adding labels / image view as subviews) via code?

Comment: I am setting .image property of profileImageView in cellForRowAt method of table view. I used Prototype Cell in storyboard, It has a single image View, i am also attaching it's screen shot, please check!

Comment: DonMag screenshot is added, see i have only one image view i.e. profileImageView, whose .image is set in `cellForRowAt` and cornerRadius is applied in `awakeFromNib()`, and as mentioned earlier i had used several methods but no result!

Comment: The "placeholder" image looks off-center, which is why I say it appears to be another image view. Can you update your post with your full cell class and `cellForRowAt` function? (and any other code that is influencing the cell?)

Comment: DonMag thanks alot for your concerns, I've sorted this out. Actually i was making a blunder, where instead of setting .image property of profileImageView, i was setting it like cell.imageView?.image and it was appearing as a separate image. If you want, you may answer your first comment as the answer, so that i may mark it correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the OP...

In `cellForRowAt` you're setting:

```
cell.imageView?.image
```

where you should be setting:

```
cell.profileImageView.image
```

A `UITableViewCell` has "built-in" `.textLabel`, `.detailTextLabel` and `.imageView` elements. We have to be careful not to use those objects if we've created a custom cell with our own labels / imageViews / etc.